# Как решить psql: ошибка: подключиться к серверу «localhost» (::1) не удалось?

Tags: база-данных, windows, postgresql

поставил PostgreSQL, но при авторизации возникает ошибка:

```
C:\Users\Admin>psql v-
Пароль пользователя Егор:
psql: ошибка: подключиться к серверу "localhost" (::1), порту 5432 не удалось: ВАЖНО:  пользователь "Егор" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)
```

Сразу, важная деталь, раньше учётка Windows называлась Егор, сейчас Admin, и что более важно, в реестре я заменил не все совпадения, так как их миллион, но PostgreSQL я ставил после переименования.
Переустановил 2 раза, пароль 100% правильный. Еще пробовал по советам менять пользователя, но тоже не помогло.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что еще попробовать?

Comment: А постгресс-то вообще IPv6 слушает?

Comment: Второй очевидный вариант - для пользователя Admin заперещена аутентификация по паролю (например, разрешена только по ключам). Правда, я говорю по опыту с MySql - поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если в постгресе такое невозможно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если свежепоставленный постгрес, пробуйте psql -U postgres, т.к. инсталлятор не создает в самом постгресе учеток с вашим именем

(это мне подсказали ответ, действительно при установке задаём пароль для суперюзера postgres)